# What "sad thing" did Aramina hear?

Tags: anne-mccaffrey, pern

From the last chapter of *The Renegades of Pern*, slightly abridged:

> Lessa greeted her warmly, expressing delight that Aramina had rediscovered her ability to contact Dragons.  Upon questioning, it appeared that Aramina had not heard Ramoth and Mnementh as they arrived.
>
> 'I do hear the fire lizards,' Aramina offered, 'And I also hear someone - something else - occasionally.  Whatever it is, is very sad, so I don't *try* to hear it.'

Was it ever revealed what Aramina was hearing?

Comment: http://pern.wikia.com/wiki/The_Dolphins_of_Pern

Comment: http://kumo.swcp.com/~quirk/afp3.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this was revealed at the end of *Dolphins of Pern*:

> "The song ..." Aramina said, leaning toward Menolly, "the song we heard.  Where did you hear it?"
>
>  "At night, near the sea, I must admit.  And ..." Menolly paused, frowning, "at Paradise River when I was there harpering the children.  You've heard it?"
>
>   "Yes," Aramina said in a sad, wistful tone.  "I always thought it was a dream but I wasn't always asleep when I heard it."
>
>   "When you think how long the dolphins have waited for us to acknowledge them again, it would make any creature sad." Sebell said.

See this [preview of the last few pages in Google Books](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=GpXYWTtX_eoC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA319#v=onepage&q&f=false). (Spoliers!)

Comment: Thanks.  I had considered the possibility that it was from *Dolphins*, which I've never read, but I couldn't see why the dolphins would be "very sad". :-)  (Plus, I'd somehow got the mistaken impression that *Dolphins* was one of the prequels, like *Moretta* or *Dragonsdawn*.)